# VLAN not working in trunk between SonicWALL and Cisco

Tags: cisco, vlan, sonicwall

*This was caused by me forgetting about a switch.  Continue reading only if you're very bored*

SonicWALL NSA 3500 connected to Cisco Catalyst 3850.  The SonicWALL has "sub-interfaces" (VLANs) V2, V800, and V802.  The 2 and 802 have worked fine for forever, and I am now trying to add 800, but no traffic is working through the trunk.  See the image for my configs.  I can't get a downstream "switchport access vlan 800" port with a device to connect, and on the switch I can't ping 172.16.16.7, which is the SonicWALL sub-interface IP, whereas I can ping the IP for VLAN 802.

**EDIT** - Since configuring the Cisco with "ip classless" I was able to get Spanning-Tree to get out of "BKN" status and VLAN 800 now shows up as a non-pruned VLAN in "*sh int gi1/0/2 trunk*" but my main issue of not being able to pass traffic or connect an access device on that VLAN still persists.

[image]

Here's the link to the image in case it's too small to see here: http://oi60.tinypic.com/15cllp1.jpg

**EDIT**

Switch#*sh span summ*

```
Switch is in pvst mode
Root bridge for: VLAN0800
Extended system ID           is enabled
Portfast Default             is disabled
PortFast BPDU Guard Default  is disabled
Portfast BPDU Filter Default is disabled
Loopguard Default            is disabled
EtherChannel misconfig guard is enabled
UplinkFast                   is disabled
BackboneFast                 is disabled
Configured Pathcost method used is short

Name                   Blocking Listening Learning Forwarding STP Active
---------------------- -------- --------- -------- ---------- ----------
VLAN0001                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0002                     0         0        0         14         14
VLAN0003                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0004                     0         0        0         10         10
VLAN0005                     0         0        0         10         10
VLAN0006                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0007                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0008                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0009                     0         0        0          9          9

Name                   Blocking Listening Learning Forwarding STP Active
---------------------- -------- --------- -------- ---------- ----------
VLAN0010                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0011                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0012                     0         0        0         10         10
VLAN0013                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0014                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0015                     0         0        0         11         11
VLAN0016                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0017                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0018                     0         0        0         11         11
VLAN0103                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0104                     0         0        0         10         10
VLAN0105                     0         0        0         10         10
VLAN0106                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0107                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0111                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0800                     0         0        0          9          9
VLAN0802                     0         0        0         10         10
VLAN0803                     0         0        0          9          9
---------------------- -------- --------- -------- ---------- ----------
27 vlans                     0         0        0        258        258
```

Switch#*sh span vlan 800*

```
VLAN0800
    Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
    Root ID    Priority    4896
        Address     dca5.f433.4980
        This bridge is the root
        Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

    Bridge ID  Priority    4896   (priority 4096 sys-id-ext 800)
        Address     dca5.f433.4980
        Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
        Aging Time  300 sec

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Gi1/0/2             Desg FWD 19        128.2    P2p
Gi1/0/14            Desg FWD 4         128.14   P2p
Gi1/0/15            Desg FWD 4         128.15   P2p
Gi1/0/16            Desg FWD 4         128.16   P2p
Gi1/0/17            Desg FWD 4         128.17   P2p
Te1/1/3             Desg FWD 4         128.55   P2p
Te1/1/4             Desg FWD 4         128.56   P2p
Po1                 Desg FWD 3         128.2027 P2p
Po2                 Desg FWD 3         128.2028 P2p
```

Switch#*sh int gi1/0/2 switchport*

```
Name: Gi1/0/2
Switchport: Enabled
Administrative Mode: trunk
Operational Mode: trunk
Administrative Trunking Encapsulation: dot1q
Operational Trunking Encapsulation: dot1q
Negotiation of Trunking: On
Access Mode VLAN: 1 (default)
Trunking Native Mode VLAN: 1 (default)
Administrative Native VLAN tagging: enabled
Voice VLAN: none
Administrative private-vlan host-association: none
Administrative private-vlan mapping: none
Administrative private-vlan trunk native VLAN: none
Administrative private-vlan trunk Native VLAN tagging: enabled
Administrative private-vlan trunk encapsulation: dot1q
Administrative private-vlan trunk normal VLANs: none
Administrative private-vlan trunk associations: none
Administrative private-vlan trunk mappings: none
Operational private-vlan: none
Trunking VLANs Enabled: ALL
Pruning VLANs Enabled: 2-1001
Capture Mode Disabled
Capture VLANs Allowed: ALL

Protected: false
Unknown unicast blocked: disabled
Unknown multicast blocked: disabled
Appliance trust: none
```

**See my top edit - VLAN 800 now shows up in "*sh int gi1/0/2 trunk" as a non-pruned VLAN but that didn't change my issue of not being able to connect anything on that VLAN and I still cannot ping 172.16.16.7**

Comment: Can you post the output of `show span summ` and `show span vlan 800` from the 3850? Also you can shutdown/remove the L3 SVI on the 3850, since the SonicWall is doing the routing it's unnecessary.

Comment: And please include `show int gi1/0/2 switchport`... Thanks.

Comment: I've added the outputs you asked for.  Interestingly, last night the Spanning-Tree status for the Gi1/0/2 port was BKN*, PVID_Inc until I figured out how to fix it with "ip classless" so it didn't think my 172.16.x.x's were overlapping I guess.  That still didn't fix any of the issues though.

Comment: This is a bit extreme; but you might consider getting an ethernet tap and watching the packets with a 3rd machine.

Comment: Thanks @ericx I will consider doing that today if possible.  Will report back with an edit with results.  You're talking tapping the segment between the Cisco and SonicWALL and looking at VLAN tags, correct?

Comment: Yah. If I were doing it, I'd use a FreeBSD box and watch the traffic with tcpdump and/or tshark. If you use the -e option in tcpdump, you can see the vlan tags.

Comment: Good to know on that -e option, thank you

Comment: @ericx I've got plenty of spare ports on that Cisco, would a SPAN duplicate the VLAN tags I need to see?

Comment: I don't honestly know. More to the point, I suspect one or the other of the two machines is broken and using a passive tap in between the two would allow you to see exactly what they're putting out. If you clone a port on the cisco, you're still relying on it to tell you what's going on.

Comment: PVID_Inc is Port Vlan-ID Inconsistent, meaning the switch received a mis-matched BPDU on a trunk interface (usually a native vlan config issue) so the switch is not moving the L2 interface into the forwarding state.  `IP classless` is not related to STP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh god, I'm such an idiot.  There was a switch between the Cisco and SonicWALL that I completely forgot about until I was up there about to put my network tap into place.  It should've been passing everything along, but on a whim I decided to check its config and found `switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,2,802,1002-1005` on both ports involved.  Sorry to have wasted everybody's time and brainpower.  It works now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a routing issue.  Make sure the Cisco Catalyst 3850 has a default route to the SonicWALL NSA 3500 or a route directly to the 172.16.16.0/24 destination via the SonicWALL.  Not having the proper routes would prevent the switch from being able to PING an IP address not on the same subnet.

I would be curious to know whether the device on vlan 800 could PING 172.16.16.7.

Providing some TRACEROUTE results would also be helpful from the switch to 172.16.16.7 and also to the device on vlan 800 and from the device on vlan 800 to 172.16.16.7 and also to the switch.

Comment: "sh ip route" on the Cisco says 172.16.16.0/24 is directly connected via Vlan800.  I can't get any device on VLAN 800 in order to test your second idea.  Likewise, I cannot provide any traceroute results since there is no destination to trace.

Comment: How does the Cisco have a route to 172.16.16.0/24 directly connected to vlan 800 when you have no IP address assigned?

Comment: You're right, I had put an IP on the VLAN to test and forgot to take it off.  I took it off and get "172.16.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks \ 172.16.1.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan802 \ 172.16.1.1/32 is directly connected, Vlan802" and my default gateway is "0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 192.168.200.7" which is the SonicWALL IP on VLAN 2.  And yes, Vlan802 has an IP address of 172.16.1.1 which I can remove if you need.